# Locked out from Windows 8.1 administrator account being disabled

Tags: windows-8.1, administrator

I installed a Windows 8.1 laptop.
By default the Administrator account is disabled. During the install process, the user created belongs to the administrators group (call it FirstUser).

I installed various software, I created a normal account for the user (call it RealUser), and I mistakenly deleted FirstUser account (while I was connected under this account). I rebooted and... oh well, I understood the mistake. I no longer have access to any administrative privileges.
The laptop is still in workgroup.

I tested with [Offline Windows Password & Registry Editor](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) (latest version):

1. Activated Administrator account, and blanked its password (no option to set a new one)
2. Gave RealUser account administrative privileges

After reboot, only RealUser account is still available.
Once logged in, I'm unable to access anything requiring administrative provileges.

Does anyone know a way to successfully activate the Administrator account, or whatever ?

Comment: Sounds like you have enough goofiness going on with the accounts at this point that it is probably worth it to start over and re-install windows 8 correctly.

Comment: One thought.  ntpasswd claims it can work even on 8.1, but the docs seem to miss one point: "fast startup".  _Windows 8 shutdown now uses hibernation by default, which leaves its filesystems mounted and unsafe to access_.  Before you booted the ntpasswd disc, did you use "reboot" from Windows, instead of shut down & then power on?  If not, I would definitely try it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using the relevant utilities in HBCD or Win7Live (from reboot.pro) doesn't help for some reason, you could try replacing the sethc.exe (from an external OS of course) like in this tutorial:
http://4sysops.com/archives/forgot-the-administrator-password-the-sticky-keys-trick/

Comment: I used a similar trick as sethc.exe several times before, but I didn't remember about it. Thank!

Answer (score -2):

Try to activate the built in administrator account. open command prompt and enter "**net user administrator /active:yes**"

OR try going into local users and groups,

1. Press the Windows + R keys to open the Run dialog, type lusrmgr.msc and click/tap on OK.
2. In the left pane, click/tap on the Users folder, then in the middle pane, double click/tap on Administrator.
3. Go into general properties and unlock administrator account.

This website might be of use to you: [LINK HERE](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9650-built-administrator-account-enable-disable-windows-8-a.html)

Worst case scenario you can re-install windows with the recovery disk or just download a windows 8 ISO and use the stickers activation code on your PC.

Comment: Your solution require admin privileges...
And offering reinstallation is just an overkill.

Comment: Worst case scenario yes replace OS. He didn't forget the password he deleted the admin account. Just use Offline NT Password iso cd. Boot with it and activate hidden Administrator account. After logging with it make new account with administrator privileges. Its sounds like what you did should work, I have had the same issue and fixed it this way. Here i found a link. (http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/376275-accidentally-deleted-windows-8-administrator-account)